# Reason for ACID property support in ORC tables

Tags: hive

Hive supports ACID property only for ORC formatted tables.
Can anyone please let me know the reason or any guide available ?

Answer (score 0):

It's the current limitation, Here's the text from official documentation:

> Only ORC file format is supported in this first release.  The feature has been built such that transactions can be used by any storage format that can determine how updates or deletes apply to base records (basically, that has an explicit or implicit row id), but so far the integration work has only been done for ORC.

More details about Hive transactions can be found [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions)

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific reason per say.
More formats will be supported in later versions. ORC was the first one to be supported.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions